# how do you check whether the attempted computation of topological sorting is indeed one

Tags: algorithm

i need to check if the topological sorting computation is one on the following graph:

```
0->1->2->3
|  ^
v  |
4<-5<-6<-7

5->0
3->6
7->2

i have determines that the topological sorting is: 0 1 2 3 7 6 5 4
```

how do you check if the computation of this topological sorting is one?

Comment: Assuming that 3 goes back to 6 in your notation, then you have a cycle and thus can't topologically sort it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to test for every node `n` in the ordered list that each node from an incoming edge `in` appears before `n` in the ordered list:

```
isTopologicallySorted(list, graph)
    for each n in list
        for each in in graph[edges incoming at n]
            if list.indexof(in.source) > list.indexof(n) then return false
    return true
```

Of course, every node should appear exactly once in the list.